# Wordpress shortcodes not working on posts but wornikg on pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

When I use shortcode on page works good but on posts is displayed only shortcode name.
Example shortcode:

```
function foobar_func( $atts ){
    return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

Usage:

```
[foobar]
```

On page is displayed

```
foo and bar
```

but on post only

```
[foobar]
```

I tryied on basic theme like TwentySeventenn and the problem still exists.

Comment: It must be an issue with TwentySeventeen. I have tested it on my own theme and it works.

Answer (score 1):

It's very strange. So you added the above code to TwentySeventenn theme's functions.php, but it does not work on post? Please double check you write [foobar] correctly on your post content file.
Or if you changed something on the theme, please check you used the_content() instead of echo get_the_content();
shortcodes are not working if you use get_the_content();

Comment: Sorry my fault, on TwentySeventenn theme's function.php I didn't add the code. Now on this theme works but on my theme not. Now I know that preblem is in my theme. I think that [foobar] in post editor is not interpreted. The question is why ?

Comment: If you added the add_shortcode() section above to your functions.php and used the_content() function on your template code it will work without any problem. please double check it

Comment: How cal I check if is used the_content() ?

Comment: Please check WordPress template hierarchy. [link]https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ You can find proper template file (for example single-post.php) and make sure you used the loop correctly [link]https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop